# LaTeX interpreter but sans-serif font on Matlab figures

Tags: matlab, fonts, latex, matlab-figure, text-formatting

On LaTeX I often use the `\usepackage{cmbright}` font when I want to have a clean, sans-serif font both in the text and in the mathematical formula I write.
In order to have an homogeneous result between my figures and the text, I would like the text in my figures (labels, axis ticks, title, annotations...) to be as well in this font.

Unfortunately so far on Matlab, when using the LaTeX interpreter, only the default font is available. I would like to be able to write both text and mathematical formulas in a sans-serif font (and the same for both text and math) on the figures I plot.

Also, I would need to export the result as .eps figures (preserving the sans-serif font and all).
Any idea?

I am on Mac OS 10.14.1 (Matlab 2018a) and also on Ubuntu 18.10 (Matlab 2018b).
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You want to use [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export_fig). For text, simply write a placeholder, and replace it in LaTeX (e.g. using [`psfrag`](https://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag)). That is the best way to match fonts exactly.

Comment: Save your results as csv files and then use pgfplots and pgfplotstable to load and plot it in LaTeX, this give imho by far the best results.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but for now, I just save my images in .eps on Matlab and then modify them on Illustrator or Inkscape in order to replace any text manually with a LaTeX compiled expression (using LaTeXit on Mac for instance). I was looking for something more straightforward, just in Matlab, in order to create the figures independently from the LaTeX article I am writing (so I can reuse the figure for an oral presentation for instance).

Comment: Are you familiar with [matlab2tikz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz)? It converts matlab figures to TikZ/Pgfplots files which can be rendered by LateX. The script has plenty of options, so it can probably be configured to your needs.
If you have more questions on the TikZ aspect: head on over to https://tex.stackexchange.com/, there are plenty of questions and people there who can help you.